# Svelte build initial render to index.html file

Tags: javascript, html, svelte, sapper

I've decided try out Svelte for my next website, and this will be a static website hosted using GitLab pages.

I got the basic compilation working which generates `dist/bundle.js` and `dist/bundle.css`.

The issue is that I cannot upload this `dist` folder as there is no `index.html` file.

How do I get Svelte/rollup to generate an `index.html` file which contains the **initial** render?

---

The other option is to create my own `index.html` file and import `bundle.js`. This is not an option for me because the initial render is now generated at runtime via javascript instead of at compile-time, potentially having a negative SEO impact and preventing users without javascript from at least seeing something.

---

I was also looking at Sapper which does server-side rendering, which, from what I know, does an initial rendering server-side. However, this seems to require you to have a server instead of rendering to a file, and seems overly complicated for a static single-page website.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After digging around for a while, I found out that [Sapper](https://sapper.svelte.dev) allows you to [export](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Exporting) (render to html files instead of requiring a server).

You can do this by using the `sapper export` command. You can also easily switch to an express server if required.

This has the following benefits over a normal svelte compilation and over some other frameworks:

- Better SEO
- Possibly better accessibility
- Faster page loads due to initial page render
- JavaScript not required to view non-dynamic sections of your page
- Component-scoped javascript still available at runtime
- No runtime and virtual DOM - faster and smaller javascript bundle

Comment: Looks like sapper has been superseded by SvelteKit (by the same people): https://kit.svelte.dev

Answer (score 4):

I have recently started experimenting with Svelte and started by downloading the [hello world example](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.6.9).
I then just started altering it for my needs.
It already has an `index.html` file set up in the public folder (it is set up to compile to the public folder instead of dist). Svelte / Rollup will not generate an `index.html` file, it is purely for compiling and bundling your JS / Svelte components.

The `index.html` file supplied is just basic:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>

    <title>Svelte app</title>

    <link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='favicon.png'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='global.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='bundle.css'>
</head>

<body>
    <script src='bundle.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `main.js` looks like this:

```
import App from './App.svelte';

var app = new App({
  target: document.body
});

export default app;
```

Here is a link [[source]](https://github.com/2pha/svelte-three-shaders), [[build]](https://2pha.github.io/svelte-three-shaders/public/) to my first svelte app if you're interested.

As far as SEO is concerned, I hear all over the place for years that google can crawl JS now, but I am not convinced. A JS driven SPA will never have the SEO juice that a standard html page will.

That being said, I am currently working on an SPA with svelte that I want good SEO for. The interactive part is only a small part of the page, so I am adding the rest (text, images and stuff) directly to the `index.html` so search engines should have no problem crawling it. I just change the `main.js` to inject the app into a div (with the ID of app) rather than the body.
So the `main.js` looks like this:

```
import App from './App.svelte';

var app = new App({
  target: document.getElementById('app'),
});

export default app;
```

I have not yet done anything with Sapper so I can't comment on that.

I hope my answer helps in some way.

Comment: I actually did start with that hello world example and that's when I decided to ask this question. If I put the static content in `index.html`, it defeats my purpose of using svelte because my website is mainly static and the only dynamic parts will be maybe a hamburger menu. So I intend to use Svelte as more of a html compiler than a js compiler due to my lack of dynamic parts, similar to next.js and react static and a few others (which have the issue of either not allowing any client-side javascript inside components or require the entire react runtime which I'mtrying toavoid byusing Svelte)

Comment: Then it seems to me that you don't need svelte at all (or any JS framework). A menu can be made with minimal CSS and maybe a small amount of JS. Maybe a static site generator would more suit your needs. I persoannly use metalsmith for my blog.

Comment: Svelte allows me to separate into components with scoped styles and javascript and I find it difficult to develop without this. I could use other template engines but I can't find any that have scoped css and js. I also prefer to stick with Svelte so that I can use it across projects regardless of whether I'd like to generate a static website or not. Svelte already generates a static website unless you use something like sapper, but requires javascript to generate the initial render instead of generating a html file with the initial render. I would have expected this to be a simple task.